# Require.js code organization in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, requirejs, winjs

I have a Windows 8 application written in JS that uses some of WinJS concepts:

- Pages
- Namespaces

Meanwhile it uses Backbone models and collections as well as jquery, underscore and some other popular libraries.

Every Backbone model defined in "Models" WinJS-styled namespace (ex: `WinJS.Namespace.define("Models", {mymodel: //stuff})`) and every collection in "Collections" namespace. Instances of collections and models are stored in "App" namespace.

Every page is a WinJS-styled page (ex: `WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/somepage/somepage.html", {//stuff})`). And each page has its own folder with html, css and js file.

So now I have bunch of JS files which are dependent on each other and my entry point, default.html, has giant stack of `<script>` tags ordered manually in correct load order and is quite hard to maintain with time.

**Question:**
Recently I heard about require.js and looks like it solves my problem, it loads modules in correct order considering dependencies. But the problem is, I don't know how to refactor my code, doesn't look like WinJS.pages and WinJS.namespaces are compatible with require.js's modular style. What would be the best approach here? What are best practices?

Example of my default.html head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CollectionsWinJS</title>

<!-- Javascript libraries -->
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/js-yaml.js"></script>

<script src="/js/libs/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/moment.js"></script>

<script src="/js/libs/metrobone.js"></script>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- CollectionsWinJS references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/conf.js"></script>
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="/js/navigator.js"></script>

<script src="/js/data.js"></script>

<!-- Javascript namespaces -->
<script src="/js/clns.js"></script>
<script src="/js/converters.js"></script>

<!-- Sources -->
<script src="/js/Models/User.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Models/ExternalItem.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Collections/ExternalItems.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Models/Service.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Models/ServiceProvider.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Collections/Services.js"></script>
<script src="/js/Collections/ServiceProviders.js"></script>

<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: do you need to really worry about order? are the scripts dependent on each other during load/initialization flow? good to keep each script like `(function() { ... })();` this and ensure global variables are handful/none and/or use WinJS.Namespace to expose classes. in that case, long list of script tags can be thought similar to include namespace directives in c# code. for example - having a long list of using directives in c# code is ok.

Comment: You said "this solves my problem". What exactly is the problem you were looking to solve? The big advantage of require.js is that it avoids script execution until necessary, but it sounds like you might not be doing much heavy script execution.

Comment: @Sushil Pieces of code are dependent on each other. For example my Backbone collection A uses model B. So A is dependent on B.

Comment: @JeremyFoster problem is: I do not know how to combine WinJS namespaces with require.js modular system.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take an example.

```
script1.js
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var A = WinJS.Class.define( 
        function A_ctor() {}, 
        {
            property1: { .. }
            func1: ..
        });

    WinJS.Namespace.define('Models.A', { A: A });
}();
script2.js
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var B = WinJS.Class.define( 
        function B_ctor() {}, 
        {
            property1: { .. }
            func1: function func1()
            {
                var a = new Models.A();
            }
        });

    WinJS.Namespace.define('Models.B', { B: B });
}();
```

In the above scenario, there exists a runtime dependency in `B.func1` to `A` class. but it does not matter whether in initialization flow `script1` or `script2` is executed first. it is because initialization flow is only going to define the classes, they are not executed yet.

if all your scripts are properly modularized into classes and publishing through namespace themselves - the initialization code flow should be in app activation flow and may be instantiation of some global variables in default.js which can be placed at the end in default.html.

Comment: It doesn't really going to work with Backbone models definitions. model.js: WinJS.Namespaces.define("mymodels", { model: Backbone.Models.extend(...) }). collection.js: WinJS.Namespaces.define("mycollections", { collection: Backbone.Collection.extend({model: mymodels.model /*this one is set to null if collections.js is loaded first*/ }) })

Comment: if the same problem were to be handled for a webapp using backbone.js (not winjs app) - how will the models be defined - will it be one mymodels.js where model classes are declared in proper order?

Comment: I am quite new to any kind of web development and people say they use AMD loaders, that's why I asked this questions to ask people, what are other solutions :)